# django: логинит только в админку

Tags: django, django-admin

Привет !

Не получается авторизация в Django1.8.

Вобщем логинится только в админку, а на фронтенде не хочет признавать, хотя пару логин/пароль узнаёт.

Т.е. например после правильного ввода логи пароля в **accounts/login** редиректит на index.html

**index.html:**

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
  {% else %}
  ...
  {% endif %}
```

И на данном этапе не признаёт пользователя, хотя в админке вход произошёл.

Может быть кто знает или сталкивался с такого рода проблемой ?

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mixes import views as mixes_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', mixes_views.index),

    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', mixes_views.profile),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
...
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
    else:
        print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
```

**registration/login.html:**

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Спс)

**views.py:**

```
def index(request, page=1):
    data = Podcast.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    pg = Paginator(data, 7)
    podcasts = pg.page(page)

    video = Video.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    video_pg = Paginator(video, 3)
    videos = video_pg.page(1)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'data': podcasts,
        'video': videos
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя в контексте шаблона нет user. Потому и все условия в шаблоне не срабатывают.

```
request_context = RequestContext(request)
request_context.push(
    'data': podcasts,
    'video': videos
}) 
return render_to_response('index.html', request_context)
```

Ну и чтобы не возится с расширением RequestContext Почитай как работают CBV
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView

Использование CBV более предпочтительнее чем использование простых функций, хоть и выглядит по первости немного сложнее.

Comment: вставил. приходит то, что отредактировал ?

Comment: user же должен быть уже подключён автоматом в settings.py, у меня присутствует, как в доках например описывают (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates)

Comment: Верно но для этого надо использовать RequestContext как я сказал или TemplateView.

Насчет request.user, извини, привычка от старых версий осталась.

Comment: да действительно, там ниже "This template context variable is not available if a RequestContext is not being used". В пример кода бы уж вставили в доках )